# Create ARM property name dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to construct property name dynamically?
I want to do something like this:

```
"resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "StorageAccounts:WritableAccountName": "[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountName.value]",
            "[concat('StorageAccounts:Accounts:', [reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountName.value])]": "[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]",
          }
        }
      ]
```

So as a result I want to have `StorageAccounts:WritableAccountName`and `StorageAccounts:Accounts:mystorageaccount` app settings created.

My approach is not working: I have an error while validating the template:

> Unable to parse language expression 'concat(...'

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not defining your app settings as part of your web app deployment rather than as a separate object? If you do that then this becomes much easier.

Comment: @SamCogan Sorry, what do you mean by separate object? I want to create an ARM template which will create a storage account, app service plan, web app and add storage account's connection string to the wep app's settings. Is it something wrong in this idea?

Comment: No nothing wrong with that. but in you can change the way you provide the app settings to be part of the web apps properties, that way your name and value are now both values, not key names, take a look at this gist - https://gist.github.com/sam-cogan/5a07cd2807e8367b95ae1bbdb26e6994

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I simply didn't know about this approach.